# Create a java service using socket

Tags: java, mongodb, sockets

I want to create a Java service that always listens a specific port to interact with the MongoDB. When I want to get data from the database, I don't need to create a new connection. Is that possible, if yes, How about performance?

Comment: AFAICS creating a new connection to access a database is pretty normal thing to do and performance could be impacted if you create a new one on each request but in the unlikely event this is a problem, you can reuse the connection.

Comment: Generally you would have the service not return data directly from MongoDB, but process it further to make it easier to use for the end user. So yes, it's quite possible.

Comment: Yes, you can. The normal approach is to use connection pool to DB, so everytime new request comes, it will take existing connection from pool and proceed. If no connection is available, it can either create new one or wait for existing one.